# cant fix Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:1.1.0:

Tags: android, gradle

im learning java via making Android App and cant fix Sync Error "Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:1.1.0:"

project build file here

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build file here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.kayosystem.honki.chapter05.lesson21"
            minSdkVersion 28
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //0608追加androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version
        //0608取消compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
        def appcompat_version = "1.1.0"

        implementation "androidx.appcompat:$appcompat_version"
        //For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
        implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
    }
```

I have maven in both the build gradle of the project and the build gradle in the app file.
This is because a synchronization error occurred when maven was written only in the build gradle of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:$appcompat_version"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
```